# Como chamar uma função dentro de um addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3, javascript-eventos

Gostaria de saber se é possível, chamar uma função dentro de um determinado evento, utilizando addEventListener().

tenho essa função, que adiciona uma recompensa ao banco de dados :

```
    //Função que adiciona uma recompensa ao banco de dados
addReward(){
    if(!this.isEditing){
    this.addDocument(this.caminho, this.recompensa).then(()=>{
      //this.loadData();//refresh view
    });
  }else{
    this.updateDocument(this.caminho, this.recompensa.key, 
    this.recompensa).then(()=>{
      this.loadData();//refresh view
    });
  }
  this.isEditing = false;
  //clear form
  this.recompensa.valor;
  this.recompensa.data;
}
```

aqui tenho a função que exibe um determinado anúncio ao usuário, preciso que quando o usuário fechar o vídeo, a função acima seja executada enviando assim o valor de sua recompensa ao banco de dados, mas sempre me retorna um erro :

```
videosInmobi() {
    let carregar = this.loading.create({content : "Carregando..."});
    carregar.present();
    let rewardConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true,
        id: 'ca-app-pub-8000726989219599/6974786599' //id videos InMobi
    };
    this.admob.rewardVideo.config(rewardConfig);
    this.admob.rewardVideo.prepare().then((result) => {
        carregar.dismissAll();
        this.recompensa.data = moment().format('L');
        this.recompensa.valor = 0.03;
        //tento fazer assim atualmente, porém ele sempre retorna um erro quando fecho o vídeo
        document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
            console.log(event)
            this.addReward(this.recompensa);
        })
    }), carregar.dismissAll();   
}
```

o erro que me retorna é o da imagem abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo diretamente a questão:

> Como chamar uma função dentro de um addEventListener?

O EventTarget.addEventListener() precisa de no mínimo dois parâmetros. Um [tipo de evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) e um listener, que pode ser um objeto do tipo EventListener ou, mais simplesmente, uma função como no exemplo abaixo.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.js-button')

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Obrigado!')
})
```

```html
<div class="js-button"> CLICA EM MIM </div>
```

Respondendo ao contexto:

O erro no seu código está em chamar um this.addReward que não existe. Se você der um console.log no this dentro do addEventListener vai ver que esse método não existe pois o this corresponde ao contexto do listener.

`document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.addReward(this.recompensa);
  })`

Não sei como o seu código está formatado mas talvez só chamar `addReward(this.recompensa)` resolva.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Porém se eu tento colocar apenas addReward(this.recompensa). Ele me retorna um erro de sintaxe, e nem permite que eu execute o aplicativo para testar.
Estou trabalhando no ionic, por isso estou chamando ele através do this, se não ele me retorna justamente esse erro de sintaxe.
Fazendo o teste do console.log, me retornou um #document no console, ao imprimir o this.

Comment: Eu tenho zero experiência em Ionic mas achei um [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/calling-a-function-from-a-listener/58814) que talvez ajude.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou verificar esse link. Isso parece ser exatamente o que preciso. Agradecido pela ajuda e disponibilidade.